# Firebase error: Data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request

Tags: json, firebase, export, firebase-realtime-database

I need to **export** my **Firabase** database as **JSON** via the Firebase console, however when I do so I get the following message in the JSON file:

> Data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a
>   single request

How can I fix this?

---

**Additional details:**

This is the function I use in the console:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

I found this question that tried to access "too big" data from a Firebase client. I presume the two are related (Firebase limit). However I would have expected the Firebase console UI to provide that error message when exporting and ask the user whether or not to split the export in multiple files. I believe that this is a **UX bug in the JSON Export functionality** of the Firebase console (should be greyed out if not possible to export or should allow the user to tune the file size).

Answer (score 6):

install Firebase CLI,then open a terminal and write down this command in order to download the whole data base

```
firebase database:get -o OUTPUT_FILE_NAME.json /
```

Comment: You should add also a path to DB like "firebase database:get /data -o export.json"

Comment: If you're like me you probably want/need to specify project on the line: `firebase database:get --project myproject /the/path/whichmuststartwithslash -o export.json`

Comment: This method is also blocked now.

Comment: While I am fire above command on terminal then I am getting "Error: An unexpected error has occurred.". Is anyone assist me here?

Answer (score 4):

The Firebase Console has limits on the size of data it allows to export. The export link should indeed be disabled when you're displaying a location that is too big to export through the console.

If your database is under 256MB, you can export it with a CURL request:

```
curl "https://yours.firebaseio.com//.json?print=pretty&auth=CREDENTIAL"
```

See the [documentation on the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

If that also doesn't work, you'll have to download the data in chunks. A tool that might be helpful with that is: https://github.com/alexklibisz/firebak

See also:

- [Is it possible to backup Firebase DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910784/is-it-possible-to-backup-firebase-db/27957431#27957431)
- [Loading Bulk data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349459/loading-bulk-data-in-firebase/32361810#32361810)
- [How to migrate data & settings from one firebase to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549299/how-to-migrate-data-settings-from-one-firebase-to-another)

Comment: What is CREDENTIAL?

Comment: They're now called legacy tokens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#legacy_tokens